# In Linq, what's the difference between .FirstOrDefault and .SingleOrDefault

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I don't know the difference between `FirstOrDefault` and `SingleOrDefault`. When should I use the first and when should I use the second?

Comment: Some really good conversations here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745691/linq-when-to-use-singleordefault-vs-firstordefault-with-filtering-criteria

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`FirstOrDefault()` is for when zero or more results are expected to be present in the input collection and the call returns the first item if there are multiple results, Default if none.

`SingleOrDefault()` is for when zero or one result is expected in the input collection and the call returns the one result if exactly one result is present, Default if no results and exception if more than one result.

Answer (score 7):

SingleOrDefault will throw a "Sequence contains more than one element" exception if more than one item exists.

Answer (score 0):

firstordefault it will take number of rows but will just return first one of it if it is
                null it can handle the exception 
First it will take number of rows but will just return first one of it if it is
                null it will throw the exception 
singleordefault it will take only one row but will return it can handle exceptions if it is null
single it will take only one row but will return it & cannot handle exceptions

If your result set returns 0 records:

SingleOrDefault returns the default value for the type (e.g. default for int is 0)
FirstOrDefault returns the default value for the type
If you result set returns 1 record:

SingleOrDefault returns that record
FirstOrDefault returns that record
If your result set returns many records:

SingleOrDefault throws an exception
FirstOrDefault returns the first record
Conclusion:

If you want an exception to be thrown if the result set contains many records, use SingleOrDefault.

If you always want 1 record no matter what the result set contains, use FirstOrDefault