# Correct query linq

Tags: c#, linq

I already use linq but search id only and it worked perfectly

```
var obj = (from VAR in db.infos
           where VAR.id == 22                                                                                
           select new
           {
               title = VAR.title,
           }).SingleOrDefault();
Label2.Text = obj.title.Trim();
```

If I try to search by location get a error

```
var obj = (from VAR in db.infos
           where VAR.location.Trim() == "Lim"
           select new
           {
               title = VAR.title.Trim(),
           }).SingleOrDefault();

        SearchJob.Items.Add(obj.title.Trim());
        Label2.Text = obj.title;
```

Have a error in label2 line

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How do I fix it?

```
if (obj.title != null)
{
    SearchJob.Items.Add(obj.title.Trim());
    Label2.Text = obj.title;
}
```

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

**SOLUTION**

Change `SingleOrDefault()` to `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Are you sure "Lim" is in the data? You query for SingleOrDefault. You could get a null as a result.

Comment: check whether you are getting null result from linq query.

Comment: @Did you try with `FirstOrDefault()` this link might be useful for you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745691/linq-when-to-use-singleordefault-vs-firstordefault-with-filtering-criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing some nasty stuff there, VERY bad habits. For instance this:

```
var obj = (from VAR in db.infos
           where VAR.location.Trim() == "Lim"
           select new
           {
                title = VAR.title.Trim(),

           }).SingleOrDefault();

SearchJob.Items.Add(obj.title.Trim());
Label2.Text = obj.title;
```

Is a nonsense! Let me tell you why:

Always check the data BEFORE you insert it into your database, not AFTER. You're creating a lot of unnecessary overhead this way, which could be avoided altogether. Trim the data before, never after.

Next thing - you need only a single string value, yet you create an anonymous object. WHY? Do this instead:

```
string title = (from o in db.infos
                where o.location == "Lim"
                select o.title).SingleOrDefault();
```

Use `SingleOrDefault` if you expect a single result or none. However, if you expect multiple results and want only the first, use `FirstOrDefault`.

As you can see, I'm using `o` instead of `VAR`. It's true it doesn't really matter that much, BUT, it's never a good idea to use a word that's very similar to one of the reserved words (`var`).

If you get an exception `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`, it means that your query returned a null and you're trying to access a non-existing object. If your query may return null at some point, always check for null when accessing a member!

**EDIT**

```
if ( obj.title != null )
```

is bad too, because you need to check for null the object itself!

```
if (obj != null)
```

if you really want to use your bad approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error occurred in the query

In first query you have source  `db.infos`

In second you have source `db.jobinfos`

The source is changed

If we assign empty text to Label it will show, It looks like that `obj.title` does not exist or you are getting error in your query due to wrong source.

The obj is not returning title field. Check obj by debugging.

Comment: ok. are you getting the data in var ? have you debug your query ?

Comment: if ( obj.title != null )

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: It's nonsense to check `obj.title` for null, because you need to check `obj`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to skip exception :)

```
     public static class LINQException {

    public static void TryExample() {
        var LsWithEx = from p in Enumerable.Range(0, 10) select int.Parse("dsfksdj");
        var LsSkipEx = (from p in Enumerable.Range(0, 10) select int.Parse("dsfksdj")).SkipExceptions();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> SkipExceptions<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values)
    {
        using (var enumerator = values.GetEnumerator())
        {
            bool next = true;
            while (next)
            {
                try
                { next = enumerator.MoveNext();}
                catch
                { continue;}
                if (next) yield return enumerator.Current;
            }
        }
    }
}
    var obj = (from VAR in db.infos
               where VAR.location.Trim() == "Lim"
               select new
               {
                   title = VAR.title.Trim(),

               }).SkipExce.SingleOrDefault();
```