# Read List<custom class> Containing Single Record

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a list which has a single record i.e which matches to a particular ID.

Now I want to use this list's property(***i.e. a column for that single record***) without using FOREACH loop as it will just cause burden for server because my program is already having lot of loops...
Can it be done??

I am filtering the records brought from ViewState based on an ID..

```
var selectedPracticeInfo = 
          (List<PropPractice>) ViewState["dicPracticesInGrupWithTimeZone"];

var selectedPracticeforEncounter = 
             from selectedPractice in selectedPracticeInfo
             where 
                selectedPractice.PracticeId 
                     == Convert.ToInt32(ddlPractice.SelectedValue)
  select new PropPractice
  {
    PracticeId = selectedPractice.PracticeId,
    PracticeName = selectedPractice.PracticeName,
    TimeZoneDisplayName = selectedPractice.TimeZoneDisplayName
  };
```

I am planning to do something like this which will pull out the TimeZoneDisplayName of that Single record directly but it says "String cannot be used as Boolean"..

```
var practiceTimeZoneName 
       = selectedPracticeforEncounter
               .Single(practice=>practice.TimeZoneDisplayName
```

So,I wanted to ask if it can be done by some way except **FOREACH**??

Comment: Using LINQ doesn't mean you avoid loops - you just don't see the loops.

Comment: Note also, `IList<T>` has a `ForEach<T>` but I agree with what @oded says.

Comment: Why would you use a foreach on a list with a single element?

Comment: If you are sure there will be always only 1 record, you can do it quick&dirty way: selectedPracticeforEncounter[0].TimeZoneDisplayName, but I'd check if selectedPracticeforEncounter has any elements first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this something like you require? First Or Default will ensure you get a single record or null

```
var result = selectedPracticeInfo
             .Where(m=> m.PracticeID == (Int32)ddlPractice.SelectedValue)
             .FirstOrDefault();

if(result != null){

var timezone = result.TimeZoneDisplayName;

}
```

result will be a type of PropPractice but for good practice use strongly defined where you can

```
PropPractice = selectedPracticeInfo
               .Where(m=> m.PracticeID == (Int32)ddlPractice.SelectedValue)
               .FirstOrDefault();
```

you will not need the below to create the new object:

```
select new PropPractice
  {
    PracticeId = selectedPractice.PracticeId,
    PracticeName = selectedPractice.PracticeName,
    TimeZoneDisplayName = selectedPractice.TimeZoneDisplayName
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var practiceTimeZoneName=selectedPracticeforEncounter.Single().TimeZoneDisplayName
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want a single one then try adding .SingleOrDefualt to the end of you LINQ query

```
var selectedPracticeforEncounter = (from selectedPractice in selectedPracticeInfo
                                         where selectedPractice.PracticeId == Convert.ToInt32(ddlPractice.SelectedValue)
 select new PropPractice
{
PracticeId = selectedPractice.PracticeId,
PracticeName = selectedPractice.PracticeName,
TimeZoneDisplayName = selectedPractice.TimeZoneDisplayName
}).SingleOrDefault();
```

[LINQ: When to use SingleOrDefault vs. FirstOrDefault() with filtering criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745691/linq-when-to-use-singleordefault-vs-firstordefault-with-filtering-criteria)