# How to delete in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a query:

```
var q = (from c in session.db.students
          where c.id==5
          select c);
```

How can I delete this record? I've tried `deleteonsubmit`, `deleteobject`, `delete`... but none of them are not known.
For example in code below, delete not known:

```
foreach (student s in q)
{ s.deleteobject;}
session.db.savechanges();
```

or:

```
var q = (from c in session.db.students
          where c.id==5
          select c).deleteOnSubmit();
```

None of them is not defined.... where is the problem?

Comment: why did you store you DBContext in session ?
And did you try with `db.students.remove(s);`

Comment: @EmmanuelM. i use remove but i see this error: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<WindowsFormsApplication1.PurchUtility>.Remove(WindowsFormsApplication1.PurchUtility)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: can you show us the code that failed using `.Remove` it looks like you not using the right context member or entity Type

Comment: @EmmanuelM. IEnumerable<Sponser> w = (from s in Session.DB.Sponsers where s.Id == 1 select s); foreach(Sponser v in w) { Session.DB.Sponsers.Remove(w); //this line is error }

Comment: What is `Session.DB`? If it's a type of your own, what's inside the `Remove` method? We can't help without this relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to call .remove([record]) on the DbContext object. Using your code you would do the following:

```
var q = (from c in session.db.students where c.id == 5 select c);

foreach (student s in q)
{
    session.db.Remove(s);
}
session.db.SaveChanges();
```

or using method based querying (to remove a single record with id 5):

```
var s = session.db.students.Where(p => p.id == 5).FirstOrDefault();
if(s != null) { session.db.Remove(s); }
session.db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: But i dont have Remove too :(                                                                         
            IEnumerable<Sponser> w = (from s in Session.DB.Sponsers
                     where s.Id == 1
                     select s);
            foreach(Sponser v in w)
            {
                Session.DB.Sponsers.Remove(w); //this line is error 
            }

Answer (score 3):

You should use `Remove`:

```
var q = (from c in session.db.students
          where c.id==5
          select c);

foreach(student s in q)
{
    session.db.students.Remove(s);
}

session.db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: i see this error in line: session.db.students.remove(s) : Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<WindowsFormsApplication1.PurchUtility>.Remove(WindowsFormsApplication1.PurchUtility)' has some invalid argument

Answer (score 1):

Try using dbcontext, you can use remove or removerange.

```
using (var MyContext= new CRMDBContext(connString))
                {
                    MyContext.[Table].RemoveRange(MyContext.[Table].Where(x => x.[column]== [column]));
                    MyContext.SaveChanges();
                }
```

Comment: no... problem not solved yet,  i want to delete from query. not in a range

Answer (score 1):

Look this answer. maybe it will help

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17723658/4571664

then also you can use this

```
 ((DbContext)dbContext).Set<objectName>().Remove(singleObject);
 dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

if you need multiple object delete, you can use this code in foreach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Remove() or RemoveRange() methods on your context for deleting objects.

**If you have collection of objects:**

```
session.db.students.RemoveRange(collectionOfStudents);
session.db.SaveChanges();
```

**If you have just one object:**

```
session.db.students.Remove(oneStudent);
session.db.SaveChanges();
```