# Not able delete Entity from another Entity container

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
//Repository Method

public void Delete(int id)
{
    using (var scope = new UnitOfWork(_container))
    {
        var entity = AuthorService.GetById(id);
        scope.Container.Authors.DeleteObject(entity);
    }     
}
```

Ninject binding

```
public class LibraryManagerInjectModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<LibManagerContainer>().To<LibManagerContainer>().InThreadScope();
    }
}

//Author Service Class

public static class AuthorService
{
    private static LibManagerContainer Container
    {
        get { return MF.MF.Get<LibManagerContainer>(); }
    }

    public static Author GetById(int id)
    {
        using (var scope = new UnitOfWork(Container))
        {
            return Container.Authors.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        }
    }

    public static Author GetByName(String name)
    {
        using (var scope = new UnitOfWork(Container))
        {
            return Container.Authors.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);
        }
    }
}
```

Using this code i m not able to delete the entity from database. it show me an error that entity not belong to same object state manager but  i create the libContainer object inThreadscope but never able to delete the entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to load entity from db to delete record. `Id` is enough to know, and it resolves another context problem:

```
var employer = new Employ { Id = 1 };
ctx.Employ.Attach(employer);
ctx.Employ.Remove(employer);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Taken from here: [Delete a single record from Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723276/delete-a-single-record-from-entity-framework)

P.S. Something wrong with your architecture. A single context should be used within one scope.

Comment: I think this is not standardized way for deleting the object,but Thanks a lot for your reply

Comment: @AnkitRana, this approach produces one SQL command instead of two, and, moreover, it is the official tip from MSDN: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/27/tip-9-deleting-an-object-without-retrieving-it.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The `DataContext` you use to retrieve the `entity` tracks the entity, to be aware of changes to it. Because of that, you are not able to save entities retrieved from one `DataContext` (or `UnitOfWork` in your case) using another.
As you mentioned in the comments, deleting should be another transaction. To achieve this you should delete by id, not the object.
Just add a `RemoveById` method to `AuthorService`:

```
public  static class AuthorService
{
    ...

    public static void RemoveById(int id)
    {
        using (var scope = new UnitOfWork(Container))
        {
            var author = Container.Authors.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
            Container.Authors.Remove(author);
        }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: but these two trans, action is different different transaction, one is read entity from database and another is delete the selected entity. I m using the Ninject DbContext in Threadscope. then why we need to pass scope.

Comment: because you are deleting by `object`. If you want these to be 2 different transactions, you'd have to delete by id.

Comment: Thank for your reply, my concerned is to shared the EF Container instance to all our web app.but i think each container object has its own state management for object.