# Error :The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager

Tags: c#

I want to exchange db.Products.SingleOrDefault(n => n.ProductID == id) by method Delete in class Product_BLL but error "The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager".

This is my code:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        if (id.ToString() == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        //public class Product_BLL { 
            //public static Product Delete(int id)
            //{
            //LOLShopEntities db = new LOLShopEntities();
            //var p = db.Products.SingleOrDefault(n => n.ProductID == id);
            //return p;
            //}
        //}
        var p = Product_BLL.Delete(id);

        //var p = db.Products.SingleOrDefault(n => n.ProductID == id);
        if (p == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        db.Products.Remove(p);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: Check that the object exists before deleting it ?

Comment: but if i use  var p = db.Products.SingleOrDefault(n => n.ProductID == id);
No error

Comment: Yes, because if you look up the object first it's attached to the ObjectStateManager. I'm guessing you need to put `db.Products.Attach(p);` before the line `db.Products.Remove(p);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete a single record from Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723276/delete-a-single-record-from-entity-framework)