# Fast search of objects in a collection

Tags: c#, performance, search, collections

I'm writing a C# application that should do a fast search inside of an array.
I have a big collection that I'm loading from a file of objects of the following type

```
public class Info {
   public long Start { get; set; }
   public long End { get; set; }
   public string Info { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

I need a fast way to find an object in that array where 
Start <= SomeValue && End >= SomeValue

Need only the first match.

Please advice me what collection type should I use
and may be a faster algorithm than just iterating through the objects.

**SOLUTION**

"interval tree" structure was the best solution for me. It seems like > 30 times faster than iterating items in a collection until find and it took less than 1 ms to find items. Used this implementation https://github.com/mbuchetics/RangeTree

Thanks a lot guys

Comment: If it's ordered, a binary search would be very simple to implement and reasonably (log N) fast. And it doesn't need anything more than a simple array. You don't even have to load it to memory, in fact - it will work just fine with random access to the file.

Comment: Is the data ordered by either? If you can quickly find the region to scan on either (binary search, or a `SortedList<T>`, etc) - then you should be fairly sorted, no?

Comment: @Luaan But that would be very slow and not IO efficient.

Comment: @max If you can choose the layout then use an interval tree or an external interval tree. A Google search should find a few implementations :)

Comment: @LasseEspeholt: Not necessarily. That depends on many assumptions about hardware, and even the OS.

Comment: Could you tell me please, how should it be ordered? by start and end (both)?

Comment: @Max What does 'first match' mean? The lowest `Start` or just any match?

Comment: @Max You have to figure that out based on your actual use case. What kind of data is there? Which will be more useful? Can the ranges overlap?

Comment: @Luaan Nope, that is simply not true. Your idea would induce O(log N) I/O's no matter what OS you use. An I/O efficient version would induce O(log (N/B)) I/O's where B is the block size.

Comment: @LasseEspeholt: So, if the OS decides to cache the whole file in memory, there's going to be O(log N) I/O? Vista does that, you know :) And it does read in blocks too.

Comment: @Luaan But now you assume the whole file can be in memory? And to cache the whole file in memory you have to read the whole file :)

Comment: @LasseEspeholt: No, I'm assuming you're going to use testing and profiling to determine what's best for you.

Comment: @Luaan (Assuming he has a choice about the layout of the file.) But I can tell you that if it's a file, then your approach would not give the best performance. I don't need profiling for that. If you like to learn more, then we should move to chat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42498/discussion-between-lasse-espeholt-and-luaan)

Answer (score 2):

Use LINQ `FirstOrDefault`. This will return the first matching item in the collection or `null` if nothing is found.

```
infoList.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Start <= someValue && i.End >= someValue);
```

Comment: I've tried linq and it took a bit more than just iterating untill match. about 30 ms for linq and about 20 for iteration

Comment: @Max: Yes, that's to be expected. LINQ is used to make the code readable, not the best performing. That's all about priorities - use LINQ where performance is not an issue, and write manual code (which carries the price of harder maintenance) where performance is critical. That's what profiling is for.

Comment: A 10ms difference is unlikely to hurt you at all. Unless you have proof that it really is a bottleneck for your application, e.g. when  you run this query a lot within a very short time, you really shouldn’t need to micro-optimize it.

Comment: @poke In fact I need to run it a lot of times per second, I'm processing a click stream. So 10 ms is quite a good optimization in my case.

Comment: @Max Well, if you are actually running this a lot, then you should prepare your data (once) so that a query on it is more efficient. For a start, sorting it would probably help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ParallelLinq to get even faster results:

```
//Some values
long start = 0;
long end = 100;

Info result = infoList.AsParallel().FirstOrDefault(i => i.Start <= start && i.End >= end);
```

Comment: Not by me, but AsParallel is running twice slower that a simple FirstOrDefault

Comment: its slower than a non parallel version on a small dataset, but should be more performant on a large dataset

Comment: @Max: Also, it will not be faster if you don't actually have some free cores to do the parallel work. If you're using a virtual server or an old PC, you're not going to get any benefit. Also, there's a difference between startup costs and execution costs - pick what's better for your use case. Test.

Answer (score 1):

Hello dear you can search in an array fastly by using binaray search this is the fasted machanisim for searching in an array ....

Hope this will help you!

```
public static int BinarySearch(int[] arr, int lowBound, int highBound, int value)
{
    int mid;
    while (lowBound <= highBound)
    {
        mid = (lowBound + highBound) / 2;
        if (arr[mid]<value)
        {
            lowBound = mid + 1;
            continue;
        }
        else if (arr[mid] > value)
        {
            highBound = mid - 1;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            return mid;
        }
    }
    return -1;//value not found
}
```

Comment: In an *ordered* array. Don't forget that :)

Comment: @Max: Also, you can use the `Array.BinarySearch` method. No need to write your own.

Comment: You welcome Max but remember one thing don't forget to sort an array by using the method  ArrayObj.Sort();   It will automatically sort your array or for testing purpose must you us sorted array

Answer (score 0):

you can use (because it will be faster)

```
infoList.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Start <= x.SomeValue && x.End >= x.SomeValue);
```

or

```
infoList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Start <= x.SomeValue && x.End >= x.SomeValue);
```

here an explanation:

> Whenever you use SingleOrDefault, you clearly state that the query
>   should result in at most a single result. On the other hand, when
>   FirstOrDefault is used, the query can return any amount of results but
>   you state that you only want the first one.

Comment: this will raise exception ( if theres more)

Comment: ... and it does a simple scan, going one item to another, so it's at best O(N) complexity.

Comment: it will raise exception again

Comment: @JulieShannon If more than one item in the collection matches, an exception will be thrown.  What you've changed is that if nothing is found, `null` is returned.

Comment: do you think its faster than FirstOrDefault?

Comment: yes it will  be faster  take a look at the answer in  this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745691/linq-when-to-use-singleordefault-vs-firstordefault-with-filtering-criteria

Comment: `SingleOrDefault` still needs to look at *every item* in the collection, to ensure that there is indeed only a *single* match. So it will be definitely slower than `FirstOrDefault` which returns as soon as it finds *any* match.

Comment: @JulieShannon I don't see how your explanation deduces to `.SingleOrDefault` being faster.

Comment: it's somthing like when use =  in  sql query and exits try to google to see the difference