# EF LINQ to Entites query for a Many to Many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, many-to-many

trying to work out how to do LINQ to Entities query for a many to many relationship which has a junction with fields table.

Below are the Domains models (I am using View models, but keeping it simple for this example).

```
Student Domain model
StudentID (PK)
ICollection<StudentCourse> StudentCourses

StudentCourse Domain model
StudentCourseID (PK)
StudentID (FK)
CourseID (FK)
ForAdult
ForSeniour
Description

Course Domain model
CourseID (PK)
ICollection<StudentCourse> StudentCourses
```

Note:

- Since the junction table (i.e. StudentCourse) contains fields other than the two foreign keys, EF will create an entity for this.

**Lazy Loading**

I've got this working for lazy loading. The Navigation properties have been declared with the 'virtual' keyword.

The Query way - works!

```
var student = (from s in context.Students
               where s.StudentID == id
               select s).SingleOrDefault<Student>()
```

The Method way - works!

```
Student student = context.Students.Find(id);
```

**Projection**

BUT, I would prefer to do this with projection, for performance reasons, i.e. less trips to the database.

*I'm really stuck on how to write up the LINQ to Entities query to return 1 student with (1 or) many StudentCourses.*

I don't understand thoroughly how the Entity should be shaped, if you know what I mean.
For example, I've tried:

```
var myvar = from s in context.Students
            from sc in s.StudentCourses
            where s.StudentID == id
            select s
```

What I require is to return an entity of Student with a collection of StudentCourses which could then be assigned to a Student and passed to the View model, then to the View.

Really would appreciate any help, as I've spent alot of time trying to solve this.

Also as a side note, I'm using the SingleOrDefault() method to cast the results of the var (IQueryable I think) to type Student. Is this the preferred way to cast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get EF to eagerly load the related entities by using the `Include` method.

So using your LINQ example:

```
var student = (from s in context.Students
               where s.StudentID == id
               select s).Include("StudentCourses").FirstOrDefault();
```

And using extension methods:

```
var student = context.Students.Include("StudentCourses").FirstOrDefault(id);
```

The `Student` instance that is returned will have the `StudentCourses` collection populated with related entities. This should invoke only one SQL query that joins the tables together.

To answer your aside question: I prefer to use `FirstOrDefault` most of the time as above. The difference is that `SingleOrDefault` will expect [exactly one result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745691/linq-when-to-use-singleordefault-vs-firstordefault-with-filtering-criteria) and throws an exception otherwise, whereas `FirstOrDefault` will return `null` if a student is not found.

Also, as the cast to `Student` is implicit, you don't need the `<Student>` type parameter.

Comment: This works, thank you very much. For performance reasons, I would limit the columns and filtering rows, i.e. reduce the resultset returned from the database, therefore would require Query projection.

Comment: For the benefit of others learning Eager loading, you can also do nested includes. In the above example, let's also include a SubCourse Domain mode which is a navigation property on StudentCourses (which may or may not be physically linked to the Course Domain model). Here is a snippet of code to bring back one Student, it's one or many StudentCourse(s), it's one or many Course(s), and finally it's one or many SubCourse(s): `var student = (from s in context.Students where s.StudentID == id select s).Include("StudentCourses.Course").Include("StudentCourses.SubCourse").FirstOrDefault();`