# Linq query to get an object from list of lists

Tags: c#, linq, list, collections, lambda

I have a AccountContacts class that contains a data member contacts which is a list of type ContactInfo.

Each ContactInfo class has two members. 1. List that holds ContactTypes (strings) 2. A Contact Object.

so, it looks like

```
Class AccountContacts
{
  List<ContactInfo> Contacts;
}

Class ContactInfo
{
   List<string> ContactType;
   Contact UserContact;
}
```

now If I have an AccountContacts object (ac), how can I get a Contact object where the ContactType list in ContactInfo contains a specific string.

And by the way, each ContactType list is distinct to other. So at a time on Contact object can be returned.

I tried some thing like this.

```
Contact myContact = ac.Contacts.Find(c => c.ContactType.Contains("specificString")).UserContact;
```

I am able to get myContact. just want to know is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: Your call looks fine, is there a problem with it, can't get much better than one liner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Your Code:

- You are using the [`Find` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx) which will produce a `null` result if there is no match to your condition, i.e. there is no `ContactType` matching your input.
- This will cause a `NullReferenceException` when you call `.UserContact` because you can't do `null.UserContact`.

---

### Safer - Check for `null`:

```
var contact = (ac.Contacts.Where(c => c.ContactType.Contains("specificString")).Select(c => c.UserContact)).FirstOrDefault();
```

- This uses the [`Contains` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains(v=vs.110).aspx) to determine if the list has the string you are looking for.
- If a match is found then the `Contact` will be selected
- Then the `FirstOrDefault` will take the first record or return `null`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ac.Contacts
    .Where(x => x.ContactType.Contains("string"))
    .Select(x => x.UserContact)
```

This will return list of Contacts that have "string" as ContactType.

Comment: Scott, this will return `List<Contact>`.

Answer (score 1):

If they're guaranteed to be distinct:

```
var contact = ac.Contacts.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ContractType.Contains("string"));
if (contact != null)
{
    var userContact = contact.UserContact;
}
else
{
    // handle not found situation
}
```

Comment: Will that not cause a NullReferenceException if the result is `null` and you try and access `.UserContact`?

Comment: Sure would.  Edited to help.

Comment: Just as a note I would avoid using `SingleOrDefault` without good reason, as it has to enumerate the entire collection to ensure it is distinct. `FirstOrDefault` is more performant in that it will stop trying to find results as soon as it has one. Enforcing uniqueness in the collection should be on insert/update not while enumerating the collection. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1745709/1295344). Only sharing this thought, because I used it for a while before realising the benefits of `FirstOrDefault`.