# What is the different between SIngleorDefault code writing concepts in Entity Framewrok

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, methods, coding-style

I have write one line get  one row from database  using SingleOrDefault

```
Context.TableName.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.id==1);
```

And i also write the code like

```
Context.TableName.Where(x=>x.id==1).SingleOrDefault();
```

The result gave same values. But i want to know, what is the different?

I have read some articles, but they have explained,

> Nothing Difference, differences only for coding standard.

I think the both codes are looking standard codes.

> So Please let me know, If any difference for the two types  of codes.

Also **i have same doubt for these code writing concepts**

- First()
- Single()
- FirstOrDefault()

Comment: I did't compile it. It's like the sample code

Comment: @GrantWinney , Yes. Sorry for that, i have update now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in the SQL statements generated. You can log the SQL statements easily by adding this line (Entity Framework 6)...

```
context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;
```

These 2 lines...

```
context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Id == "foo");
context.Users.Where(u => u.Id == "foo").SingleOrDefault();
```

Both return the exact same SQL statement using the SQL Server provider...

```
SELECT 
    [Limit1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Limit1].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
    [Limit1].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
    [Limit1].[SecurityStamp] AS [SecurityStamp]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (2) 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
        [Extent1].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
        [Extent1].[SecurityStamp] AS [SecurityStamp], 
        '0X0X' AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[Discriminator] = N'ApplicationUser') AND (N'foo' = [Extent1].[Id])
    )  AS [Limit1]
```

Same thing for `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == "foo");
context.Users.Where(u => u.Id == "foo").FirstOrDefault();
```

Both generate the same query:

```
SELECT 
    [Limit1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Limit1].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
    [Limit1].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
    [Limit1].[SecurityStamp] AS [SecurityStamp]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
        [Extent1].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
        [Extent1].[SecurityStamp] AS [SecurityStamp], 
        '0X0X' AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[Discriminator] = N'ApplicationUser') AND (N'foo' = [Extent1].[Id])
    )  AS [Limit1]
```

You can see that `SingleOrDefault()` does a `TOP(2)`, this is because it's ensuring there is only 1 record returned, whereas `FirstOrDefault()` doesn't care.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what technical or algorithmical difference between SingleOrDefault and FirstOrDefault or SingleOrDefault and Single - there is a lot of question with pretty good answers. For example:
[LINQ: When to use SingleOrDefault vs. FirstOrDefault() with filtering criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745691/linq-when-to-use-singleordefault-vs-firstordefault-with-filtering-criteria)

If you doubt between writing

```
Context.TableName.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.id==1);
```

and

```
Context.TableName.Where(x=>x.id==1).SingleOrDefault();
```

-- result, of course will be same. But my opinion - second sample contains redundant Where. And it is redundant may be not only technically, but and with point of view of readability of your code. And in second case it is not clear - what do you expect from you Where condition, is it especially for something or not.