# How to query a List<T>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-web-api

I am new to ASP.net and LINQ however tutorial are fairly short. I am creating a Web API project and I have created a class under my model called gender as follow.

```
public class Gender
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Language LanguageId { get; set; }
    public int InternalCode { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

I have not created a database linked to it and I haven't use Entity Framework, as I am still learning it. I created a list of genders in the controller actions just for training purpose. When I am trying to query the list with LINQ in order to be able to return the proper object I am getting a compiler error at the line `var query = from gen in Gender` below and I am not sure why.

```
    // Show
    // URI GET + api/Gender/id/
    [HttpGet]
    public Gender Gender(int id)
    {
        var genders = new List<Gender>();

        genders.Add(new Gender { Id = 1, Description = "Male" });
        genders.Add(new Gender { Id = 2, Description = "Female" });

        var query = from gen in Gender
                       where gen.Id == id 
                       select gen;
        return query;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
    var query = from gen in genders
                   where gen.Id == id 
                   select gen;
```

Query your list, `genders`, not the type `Gender`

Then you can return a single item by doing:

```
 return query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Of course you could compress all of this by doing:

```
return genders.FirstOrDefault(gen => gen.Id == id);
```

Comment: Not a big deal, but if `Id` is a primary key in the database, `SingleOrDefault` should be more appropriate. Providing an Id for an item and getting another back which shares the Id does not sound correct.

Comment: Not necessarily. `SingleOrDefault` implies a contract (it must be unique) and potentially incurs a performance penalty as it (in theory) must check all entries to ensure there is only one. You should ask if you want to enforce a contract at "query" time instead of "write" time. Also see [other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745691/linq-when-to-use-singleordefault-vs-firstordefault-with-filtering-criteria) on here