# Fetch single value with linq projection query without using FirstOrDefualt

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework and this is my view model:

```
public class UserDetailsModel:CityModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }     
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
 }

 public class VendorInCategoryModel
 {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public int VendorId { get; set; }
        public virtual CategoryMasterModel CategoryMaster { get; set; }
        public virtual UserDetailsModel UserDetails { get; set; }
 }

 public class CategoryMasterModel
 {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
 }
```

This is my query to fetch vendor details along with category details of particular vendor say `v001`:

```
UserDetailsModel workerDetails = context.UserDetails.
                                     Where(d => d.Id == _vendorId).
                                     Select(d => new UserDetailsModel
                                                 {
                                                    Id = d.Id,
                                                    Fullname = d.Fullname,
                                                    CategoryId = d.VendorInCategory.Select(v => v.CategoryId).FirstOrDefault(),
                                                 }).SingleOrDefault();
```

Here I have used `FirstOrDefault` to fetch `categoryId` (that is single value)

But I don't want to use `FirstOrDefault` as I have used in so many queries and it is giving me wrong output in some cases. So that the reason why I don't want to use `FirstOrDefault`.

When I have written `SingleOrDefualt` in place of `FirstOrDefault` it is throwing me error 
that use `FirstOrDefault`.

So how to overcome this? Can anybody please help me?

Comment: *it is giving me wrong output in some cases* - Could you give more context here?

Comment: i cant explain you here in comments

Comment: The main issue really is: you need to **understand** why `.FirstOrDefault` is giving you the *wrong results*. If you don't understand this, and don't find a way to fix this - just switching to another function isn't going to help. You need to understand your data and your queries!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like maybe your outer select is capable of returning multiple results (e.g. if there are more than one UserDetailsModel with the same Id). If it returns multiple results then your call to .SingleOrDefault() will throw an exception as it expects only a single result or no results. See [LINQ: When to use SingleOrDefault vs. FirstOrDefault() with filtering criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745691/linq-when-to-use-singleordefault-vs-firstordefault-with-filtering-criteria) for more details.