# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AuthenticationApp.Models.User>' to 'AuthenticationApp.Models.User'

Tags: c#, linq

My linq is this:

```
User us = from s in entities.Users
          where s.Username.Equals(username)
          select s;
```

Any idea why I am getting the above error?

Comment: List of username returns. Use FirstorDefault().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FirstOrDefault`:-

```
User us = (from s in entities.Users
           where s.Username.Equals(username)
           select s).FirstOrDefault();
```

Your query is returning multiple results but you are trying to store that in `AuthenticationApp.Models.User` which can hold just one object thus the conversion error.

Or better:-

```
User us = entities.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username.Equals(username));
```

**Update:**

If you are sure it will return just 1 object back, you can use `SingleOrDefault` too. Check differences between both [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1745716/1529657).

Comment: Even if I know I will get only one result?

Comment: @user3762810 - Didn't get you. What you know that there is only 1 `UserName`?

Comment: Yes, thats is the porpouse of "FirstOrDefault", if you want to get a list of users, you'd have to change the type of "us" to IQueryable<User> or use var

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error because projection returns `IEnumerable` (`IQueryable`). To get `User` by its name you can use the following:

```
try
{
    var user = entities.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Username.Equals(username));
}
catch
{
    // handle the case when there are more than 
    // one user with given name in DB
}
```