# using .SingleOrDefault() inside .Where() will raise the following exception:- System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am working on an asp.net mvc-4 web application, and i am using Entity Framework 5. now i have the following model method:-

```
 public IQueryable<TMSStorageDevice> CustomerSD(int customerid)
        {


            var customerSiteIds = entities.SiteDefinitions.Where(a => a.AccountDefinitions1.SingleOrDefault().ORG_ID == customerid).Select(a2 => a2.SITEID).ToList();
        }
```

now this will raise the following error:-

```
System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233067
  Message=The methods 'Single' and 'SingleOrDefault' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.
  Source=System.Data.Entity
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SingleTranslatorBase.TranslateUnary(ExpressionConverter parent, DbExpression operand, MethodCallExpression call)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.UnarySequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConver
```

i was able to fix this by replacing (`SingleOrDefault()`):-

```
a.AccountDefinitions1.SingleOrDefault().ORG_ID
```

with (`FirstOrDefault()`):-

```
a.AccountDefinitions1.FirsteOrDefault().ORG_ID
```

so can anyone advice on this behavior ? i mean why `FirstOrDefault()` will work in this case unlike `SingleorDefault()` ?

Comment: are you sure this can't be done differently?  You might be looking for Any() `entities.SiteDefinitions.Where(a => a.AccountDefinitions1.Any(a => a.ORG_ID == customerid))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ: When to use SingleOrDefault vs. FirstOrDefault() with filtering criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745691/linq-when-to-use-singleordefault-vs-firstordefault-with-filtering-criteria)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `SingleOrDefault` would require it to generate SQL which ensures that there is not more than 1 foreign row. Essentially, it would have to create a join which returns no rows if the count > 1

`FirstOrDefault`, however, simply allows it to generate a join and `SELECT TOP 1` (or equivalent) which is vastly easier.

It just simply isn't implemented in EF.

Comment: so is it correct to use FirstOrDefualt as i am doing now ? now i will always have one AccountDefinitions1 object, although i got a collection since this is a thid party system i am working on ,,,