# System.Data.Sqlite 1.0.99 guid comparison doesn't work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, guid

I am using System.Data.Sqlite 1.0.99 from C#, with it you can call to db with EF. I faced with the problem when selecting `FirstOrDefault` by `Guid` it return `null` (but row with such guid exists in database):

```
var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == userId); //returns null
//or
var user = context.Users.Where(x => x.Id == userId).ToArray(); //returns empty array
```

Found some information that this is known issue and it was fixed in 1.0.95, but broken again in 1.0.97 and next two solutions:

Solution 1: set the BinaryGUID property on the connection string to true:

```
Data Source=...;BinaryGUID=True;
```

Solution 2: set next environment variable (before you make the connection):

```
   Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AppendManifestToken_SQLiteProviderManifest", ";BinaryGUID=True;");
```

Solution 2 works, because (from sqlite site):

*AppendManifestToken_SQLiteProviderManifest - If this environment variable is set [to anything], it will be used by the **System.Data.SQLite.Linq.SQLiteProviderManifest** class (and the **System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderManifest** class) to modify future provider manifest tokens by appending the value of the environment variable to the existing provider manifest token, if any. Typically, in order for the constructed provider manifest token to be syntactically correct, the environment variable value [to be appended] must begin with a semicolon.*

Solution 1 doesn't work for me because, as I understand, it has an effect only on System.Data.SQLite.Linq.SQLiteProviderManifest.

**The Question:** Is there any solution to fix this behaviour not to setting environment variable?

Comment: I confirm this is still an issue with System.Data.SQLite v1.0.104.0. Solution 1 doesn't work, and solution 2 works. Adding this line in the constructor of a partial class on my Entity object does work, thanks! If you did find another solution, please post, but for now that's good enough.

Comment: I am glad my question/solution was helpful. Thanks you for reply!

Answer (score 0):

Would you try to use SingleorDefault instead of FirstorDefault?
[LINQ: When to use SingleOrDefault vs. FirstOrDefault() with filtering criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745691/linq-when-to-use-singleordefault-vs-firstordefault-with-filtering-criteria)

Example: var user = context.Users.SingleorDefault(x => x.Id == userId);