# Need to compare which user is logged in to determine which information to show

Tags: sql, asp.net, linq

It's a vendor page with multiple users having different roles.  Right now it's just 2 user types, and I have a boolean method which uses linq to sql to check if it's the user which initially made the changes for the vendor. The error I'm getting is that the sequence returns multiple.

```
 public static bool BoolUser1(string user)
    {
        bool user1Bool = false;
        if (user == String.Empty)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (user != null)
        {
            var context = new rempscoDataContext();
            string user1 = (from u in context.vendors
                            where u.user1_info_edit_user == user
                            select u).SingleOrDefault().user1_info_edit_user;
            if (user1 == user)

                user1Bool = true;
        }
        return user1Bool;
    }
```

Comment: It returns multiple because multiple rows in the database match your filter criteria, and if you use `SingleOrDefault` it will give you that error when there's multiple results. I suspect your filter isn't specific enough or you're filtering on the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

Well [SingleOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451(v=vs.110).aspx) will throw an exception if there is more than one element in the sequence.

> Returns the only element of a sequence, or a default value if the
>   sequence is empty; this method throws an exception if there is more
>   than one element in the sequence.

Perhaps your filter should be more specific. You could also iterate over the entire sequence for the value you want or try using [FirstOrDefault()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx), but that may not return the correct result.

More on the differences between SingleOrDefault() and FirstOrDefault() here:

[LINQ: When to use SingleOrDefault vs. FirstOrDefault() with filtering criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745691/linq-when-to-use-singleordefault-vs-firstordefault-with-filtering-criteria)