# IEnumerable cast error c#

Tags: c#, list, casting, ienumerable

I'll try to create a Custom Authentication and Authorization in Asp.Net MVC 5 (Code First). In the models I've created 2 class, `UserAccount` and `UserAccountModel`

I have an error on the `UserAccountModel` on

```
return listAccounts.Where(acc => acc.UserName.Equals(username));
```

the error code is not in English but is something like this:
is not possible to implicit convert `IEnumerable` to a list, use a cast

how to resolve the problem? thanks

```
//-------------------------------
//UserAccont.cs
//-------------------------------
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MvcSia.Models
{
    public class UserAccont
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Choose a name")]
        public string Name{ get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Choose surname")]
        public string Surname{ get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Email required")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "User Name required")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "User type required")]
        public string UserType { get; set; } 

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password required")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage ="Password not valid")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "User Name required")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    }
}



//-------------------------------
//UserAccountModel.cs
//-------------------------------
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcSia.Models
{
    public class UserAccontModel
    {
        private List<UserAccont> listAccounts = new List<UserAccont>();

        public UserAccont find(string username)
        {
            return listAccounts.Single(acc => acc.UserName.Equals(username));
        }

        public UserAccont login(string username, string password)
        {
            return listAccounts.Where(acc => acc.UserName.Equals(username));

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Well your method is meant to return a `UserAccont` (typo for `UserAccount`, btw) but the `Where` method just returns an `IEnumerable<UserAccont>`. Perhaps you meant `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Where`? I'd also *strongly* encourage you to follow .NET naming conventions.

Comment: Your method expecting a return type of  `UserAccont` and not an collection of `List<UserAccont>`

Comment: Don't forget to null check your returns from the login method if you change to FirstOrDefault or SingleOrDefault.  Also I would use FirstOrDefault or SingleOrDefault on your Find method and null check those as well.  If a user account is passed that doesn't exist your find would throw an exception.

Comment: Besides the fact that most of us probably know the error you tried to describe: if you're having a hard time translating exception messages to english, try http://finderr.net. It has a broad selection (if not all) of exceptions from the .NET Framework in some languages and their corresponding english translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `IEnumerable<UserAccont>` to
>   `UserAccont`.

Your method tries to return an `IEnumerable<UserAccont>` (several), but the signature says that it should return `UserAccont` (one). What you probably want is [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx), or [`SingleOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451(v=vs.110).aspx).

[LINQ: When to use SingleOrDefault vs. FirstOrDefault() with filtering criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745691/linq-when-to-use-singleordefault-vs-firstordefault-with-filtering-criteria)

When you use [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx), it will create an `IEnumerable<UserAccont>` with *all* the items that match your criteria. But the signature of your method suggests that you only want to return one item.

```
    public UserAccont login(string username, string password)
    {
        // Fetch one item instead.
        return listAccounts.FirstOrDefault(acc => acc.UserName.Equals(username));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to return `IEnumerable<UserAccount>` when the method expected `UserAccount`.

Try using a method to return a *single* user account object.

```
public UserAccont login(string username, string password)
{
    return listAccounts.Single(acc => acc.UserName.Equals(username));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return listAccounts.Where(acc => acc.UserName.Equals(username));
```

This returns an `IEnumerable<T>`

```
return listAccounts.Where(acc => acc.UserName.Equals(username)).ToList();
```

This returns a `List<T>`

```
return listAccounts.Where(acc => acc.UserName.Equals(username)).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will return "`T`" in `List<T>` in your case will be a single instance of `UserAccount` which is preferably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to just return the type of `UserAccont`, then use `FirstOrDefault`() method.

```
public UserAccont login(string username, string password)
{
        List<UserAccont> listOfUserAcconts = new List<UserAccont>();

        //Stops you throwing an Exception is username is null
        if(listAccounts.Count() > 0 && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username))
        {
            return listAccounts.FirstOrDefault(acc => acc.UserName.Equals(username));
        }
        else
        {
            return listOfUserAcconts;
        }
}
```