# How do i use linq and select just a Sum of values(field) from a datatable along with a where clause?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

```
X    Y      Z   E 
------------------
A   4.8     0   0 
B   1       0   0
C   8.52763 0   0
```

This is how my datatable looks,

I want to find the value of column Y where the value of column X is B.

I am trying to code the above using linq, which i am not good at.

So this is how i tried to do it,

```
Decimal TotalValue = (Decimal) 0.0;


TotalValue = Convert.ToDecimal(dt.AsEnumerable()
.Where(x => x.Field<string>("X").ToString()=="B")
.Select(p => p.Field<string>("Y").ToString()));
```

Note: All the columns X,Y,Z,E are of datatype string. And `dt` is a datatable with the above mentioned data.

Can some one tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: And in case if there are more than one occurrences of 'B' in the data table, is there a way to sum them all up and assign it to the variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting all values which `X` is `B`. Use `FirstOrDefault` to get the first matched item.

Comparing with `SingleOrDefault` there is some performance issue. From the [**SingleOrDefault() vs FirstOrDefault()**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745691/linq-when-to-use-singleordefault-vs-firstordefault-with-filtering-criteria).

`FirstOrDefault`**-** is usually faster, it iterates until it finds the element and only has to iterate the whole enumerable when it doesn't find it. In many cases, there is a high probability to find an item.

`SingleOrDefault`**-** needs to check if there is only one element and therefore always iterates the whole enumerable. To be precise, it iterates until it finds a second element and throws an exception.

```
   TotalValue = Convert.ToDecimal(dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => x.Field<string>("X").ToString()=="B")
    .Select(p => p.Field<string>("Y").ToString()).FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: That worked well for me ,thanks. But in case if there are more than one occurrences of 'B' in the datatable, is there a way to sum them all up and assign it to the variable?

Comment: Yes, instead of `FirstOrDefault` you can use `Sum` method.

Answer (score 1):

So your data source keeps a collection of objects, where each object has properties X / Y / Z / E. Or in database terms, you have a table with at least columns X Y Z E.

You probably know how to fetch the rows of this collection.

```
class MyData
{
     public string X {get; set;}
     public decimal Y {get; set;}
     public int Z {get; set;}
     public int E {get; set;}
}

IEnumerable<MyData> fetchedData = FetchMyData(...);
// this is where you get the data from the table which creates for instance
// your example.
```

The types of your columns may differ slightly, but the idea remains the same.

> I want to find the value of column Y where the value of column X is B.

Because of the question, it seems to me you are quite new to LINQ.

In Linq, whenever you want only certain items from your source collection, you use Where(...)

the x=> F(x) part in the where is called a lambda expression. The `x` is an identifier for an element in your source collection. `F(x)` is a boolean expression that decides whether to keep the element or to throw it away. It is similar to:

```
List<MyData> sourceCollection = FetchData();
List<MyData> resultCollection = new List<MyData>()
foreach (MyData x in sourceCollection)
{
    if ( F(x) ) 
        resultCollection.Add(x); // = Keep the item
    // else Don't keep the it
}
```

In your case, you only want to keep thos items with an X value of "B". So your `Where` will be:

```
.Where(fetchedItem => fetchedItem.X == "B")
```

Whenever you want to transform every item in a collection into a different object, use Linq Select:

```
.Select( x => F(x))
```

Here F(x) is a function that takes an element from the source collection and transforms it to an object of your output type.

It is similar to:

```
var resultCollection = new List<...>()
foreach (var item in sourceCollection)
{
    var resultItem = F(item);
    resultCollection.Add(resultItem);
}
```

In your case: you only want the value of column Y. The Select will be:

```
.Select(fecthedItem => fetchedItem.Y);
```

So the total result will be:

```
// All Y Where X Equals B:
var allYWhereXEqualsB = fetchedData
    .Where(fetchedItem => fetchedItem.X == "B")
    .Select(fecthedItem => fetchedItem.Y);
```

In words: from the sequence `fetchedData`, take only those elements with a `fetchedItem.X` equal to "B". From the remaining collection, take from every element only the value of property Y.

Simple comme bonjour! (once you know how to do it)