# Select Value from List Column Where Name Match

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a List with different columns, `Name` and `Bitrate`.

```
public class VideoQuality
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Bitrate { get; set; }
}

public List<VideoQuality> quality = new List<VideoQuality>()
{
     new VideoQuality() { Name = "High",   Bitrate = "5000K" },
     new VideoQuality() { Name = "Medium", Bitrate = "2500K" },
     new VideoQuality() { Name = "Low",    Bitrate = "500K" },
};
```

---

How do I select from the List where `Bitrate` is `High`?

Something like:

```
if (selectedQuality == "High")
{
    // Select High Bitrate from List
    string vBitrate = quality.Select(x => x.Bitrate)
                             .Where(Name = "High");
}
```

`vBitrate` should equal `5000K`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You first want to filter and then select:

```
var result = quality.Where(x => x.Name == "High")
                    .Select(x => x.Bitrate); //IEnumerable<string>
```

In query syntax:

```
var result = from x in quality
             where x.Name == "High"
             select x.Bitrate; //IEnumerable<string>
```

Notice that in any case the result if `IEnumerable<string>` and not a single item. If you want only a single item then use `FirstOrDefault`/`First`/`Single`,`SingleOrDefault`:

```
var result = quality.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "High")?.Bitrate; //string
```

*For the differences between the different methods see documentation and [LINQ: When to use SingleOrDefault vs. FirstOrDefault() with filtering criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1745691/6400526).*

Comment: Great answer. I think it could benefit on some more details on the difference between `Single()`, `SingleOrDefault()`, `First()` and `FirstOrDefault()`. Even though this wasn't part of the question, this is a point which is often neglected.

Comment: @Noceo - :) yap was worth adding

Answer (score 3):

If you expect at most *one* value to be returned, I suggest `FirstOrDefault`:

```
string vBitrate = quality
  .FirstOrDefault(item => item.Name == "High")
 ?.BitRate;
```