# Query a deleted column

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core-2.2

Here's code executed:

```
_appDbContext.Profiles.SingleOrDefault(x => (
                x.Username == model.Username 
                || x.Email == model.Email));
```

Here's the query and error message generated:

```
Failed executing DbCommand (65ms) [Parameters=[@__model_Username_0='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT `x`.`id`, `x`.`email`, `x`.`first_name`, `x`.`last_name`, `x`.`title`, `x`.`user_id`, `x`.`username`
FROM `profile` AS `x`
WHERE (`x`.`username` = @__model_Username_0) OR `x`.`email` IS NULL
LIMIT 2
```

**The query is selecting a column `user_id` that has already been deleted.**

It used to be set as a connection between **User** and **Profile**, but it has been deleted from the database as well as the entity:

```
public class Profile : BaseModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    //public string UserId { get; set; }  // Removed

    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

The **BaseModel** only contains a `Id` field

Comment: That `Id` is supposed to be the Profile Id

Comment: Is there a `UserId` in the base class?

Comment: The only property inside the `Base` is the `Id` without any prefix.

Comment: @hanabi_noir What is the exact question you have?

Comment: Are there any duplicate data on Table such as same `username` or same `email`?, if this condition is true,`SingleOrDefault` will be throw an exception. Also you can try `FirstOrDefault`, if you won't get an error or not Null data then it tells there is exists dublicate data.
More Information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745691/linq-when-to-use-singleordefault-vs-firstordefault-with-filtering-criteria

Comment: @ASLIM There's only one record in `profile` table. I'll try the `FirstOrDefault` method.