# Querying DbSet Hangs/Fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.0, entity-framework-core-3.0

I have a WebApi powered by .NET Core 3.0, EF Core 3.0 and using MediatR. Two of its domains are `Food` and `FoodType` with their corresponding `DataSet`s, having a 1-to-1 relationship. Executing the below line of code hangs/fails (I'm not sure what exactly happens but it jumps to the `return` line of code). Please note that querying the `Foods` dataset works just fine. Also note that `FoodTypes` table has records in it.

```
public async Task<Unit> Handle(CreateFoodType request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
     var foodType = await _context.FoodTypes.FirstOrDefaultAsync(type => type.Id == request.FoodTypeId);
     if (foodType == null)
          throw new Exception();

     //...bla bla bla

     return new Unit();
}
```

Below is a snippet of the code/configuration. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class Food
{
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
     public int AverageWeight { get; set; }
     //...

     public virtual int FoodTypeId { get; set; }
     public virtual FoodType FoodType { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class FoodType
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }

     public virtual Food Food { get; set; }
}
```

...and the DBContext class

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<Food> Foods { get; set; }
     public DbSet<FoodType> FoodTypes { get; set; }

     public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) { }

     protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
         base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

         modelBuilder.Entity<Food>()
            .HasOne(f => f.FoodType)
            .WithOne(ft => ft.Food)
            .HasForeignKey<Food>(f => f.FoodTypeId);
      }
}
```

Edit: Adding the Exception Stack Trace:

```
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.FirstOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.FirstOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Features.Foods.CreateFoodCommand.CreateRequestHandler.Handle(CreateFoodCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in [...redacted]
```

Comment: Can you *really* only have one food of each type? That doesn't sound right.

Comment: I see what you're saying but I've tweaked the domain names in my question to not reveal my actual code. In my real project, the 1-to-1 relationship makes absolute sense.

Comment: Do you have an exception that you can post? So this could help. 
And by the way.. FirstOrDefault can sometimes be wrong. I dont know how experienced you are but SingleOrDefault could be better. 
The id should be unique and if there is something wrong and the id is not unique you will get the first result and miss that there are more results.
SingleOrDefault will fail in that case and you will see it in you log files.

Comment: In Food class the FoodTypeId property should not be virtual.

Comment: @AndreFritzsche I'm new to EF but I'm no stranger to C#. I've never had problems with FirstOrDefault and don't see how/why it might misbehave. The exception's ```InnerException``` is null and the stack trace is too long for adding it to a comment.

@MdHasanIbrahim Tried it with and without ```virtual``` but to no avail.

Comment: @Hanna then you should read this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745691/linq-when-to-use-singleordefault-vs-firstordefault-with-filtering-criteria

When you ask for an unique Result but you ask for the first of a list, this code is smelly in my opinion.

I have seen this fail in so many cases allready you should think about it! 

But back to topic.
What Type of exception is it?

Could you share a github link with source?

Comment: @AndreFritzsche Added the exception's stack trace to the bottom of my question.

Comment: ok so i recreated you code local and it is working.
You sure have that id on database? CHeck it on db
Can you provide your connectionstring?
Have you tried some simple tings like clean the solution?