# Return an empty model when Linq query has no record

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

please I'm working on a `ASP.NET MVC` project with `Entity Framework`, and in a function I want it to return data structured by a Model ( **I use LINQ query to retrieve data that the function will return it** ).
Everything is fine when `LINQ` query has data, but when `LINQ` query has no data I got this Error :

**Error :**

> *Sequence contains no elements*

**Function :**

```
public static List<ABS_model> SELECT_Related_With_STG_Details(string STG)
{
    var R = (from A in SCHOOL_DB_Context.Con.ABS 
                join S in SCHOOL_DB_Context.Con.STGs on A.STG_ABS equals S.CD_STG
                join U in SCHOOL_DB_Context.Con.UFs on A.UF_ABS equals U.CD_UF
                where A.STG_ABS == STG
                select new ABS_model {
                    N_ABS = A.N_ABS,
                    STG_ABS = A.STG_ABS,
                    NM_STG = S.NM_STG,
                    PRN_STG = S.PRN_STG,
                    DT_ABS = A.DT_ABS,
                    UF_ABS = U.NM_UF,
                    INTTL_UF = U.NM_UF,
                    JSTF_ABS = A.JSTF_ABS,
                    JSTF_DOC_ABS = A.JSTF_DOC_ABS
                }
            ).ToList();
            
    return R;
}
```

So I want to return Null model if Query has no record ( If I can ).

So please any help?

Comment: `return R.Any() ? R : null`

Comment: Too much thanks bro this help me, but I Have a question If I use `.Single()` in the last of Query and got same error any solution you can suggest for me?

Comment: [Enumerable.Single Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.single?view=netcore-3.1) : Returns a single, specific element of a sequence. → So it needs a non empty collection

Comment: Use `.SingleOrDefault()` or `.FirstOrDefault()` based on your requirement. Check this for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745691/linq-when-to-use-singleordefault-vs-firstordefault-with-filtering-criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Priyank Panchal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1955268/priyank-panchal) mentioned

use :

```
var R = (from A in SCHOOL_DB_Context.Con.ABS 
            join S in SCHOOL_DB_Context.Con.STGs on A.STG_ABS equals S.CD_STG
            join U in SCHOOL_DB_Context.Con.UFs on A.UF_ABS equals U.CD_UF
            where A.STG_ABS == STG
            select new ABS_model {
                N_ABS = A.N_ABS,
                STG_ABS = A.STG_ABS,
                NM_STG = S.NM_STG,
                PRN_STG = S.PRN_STG,
                DT_ABS = A.DT_ABS,
                UF_ABS = U.NM_UF,
                INTTL_UF = U.NM_UF,
                JSTF_ABS = A.JSTF_ABS,
                JSTF_DOC_ABS = A.JSTF_DOC_ABS
            }
        ).ToList();

return R.Any() ? R : null
```

Comment: it does not compile, please add the missing `;`

Comment: If you copy-paste your code you will get the following error: "CS1002 ; expected"

Answer (score 1):

Try this out, should work:

```
var R = from A in SCHOOL_DB_Context.Con.ABS
                join S in SCHOOL_DB_Context.Con.STGs
                   on A.STG_ABS equals S.CD_STG
                join U in SCHOOL_DB_Context.Con.UFs
                   on A.UF_ABS equals U.CD_UF
                where A.STG_ABS == STG
                select new ABS_model
                {
                    N_ABS = A.N_ABS,
                    STG_ABS = A.STG_ABS,
                    NM_STG = S.NM_STG,
                    PRN_STG = S.PRN_STG,
                    DT_ABS = A.DT_ABS,
                    UF_ABS = U.NM_UF,
                    INTTL_UF = U.NM_UF,
                    JSTF_ABS = A.JSTF_ABS,
                    JSTF_DOC_ABS = A.JSTF_DOC_ABS
                };
if(R.Any())
{
   return R.ToList();
}
else
{
   return null;
}
```