# C# Refactor LINQ query of Dictionary into a single lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am relatively new C# programmer and trying to improve my LINQ query skills. I prefer using method chaining for my queries but I am struggling. Is it possible to refactor this LINQ into a single lambda expression? The code here is a simplified example. My goal is to return the Value of Key=1 in a single line. I want the LINQ query to search and return a string value of Key 1 in single Lambda expression. Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace DictionaryPractice
{
    class Program
    {        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> myd = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            myd.Add(1, "one");
            myd.Add(2, "two");
            myd.Add(3, "three");
            myd.Add(4, "four");
            
            foreach (var i in myd)
                Console.WriteLine(i.Value);
            Console.WriteLine("");

            var b = myd.Where(c => c.Key == 1).Select(c => c.Value).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine($"Desired output: {b[0]}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The expected output is [included](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YHxqi1) but you also write all values before that. What's the problem? When writing a question about expected output, you must also state the actual output that doesn't match the expectation.

Comment: You should not use linq to query dictionary by key in the first place, it's just not a right tool for this particular job. Dictionary is already optimized to query data by key.

Comment: I agree that as a dictionary, there is no need for linq when searching for an item with specific key, but for learning purposes, you could do: `Console.WriteLine($"Desired output: {myd.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Key == 1)?.Value}");`

Comment: Ok sorry for not being clear. I need my LINQ query to return a string. This example is a very simplified example of what I am really working on. The purpose of the LINQ query is to search the Dictionary based on Key and return the Value as a string. I'd like to refactor that as a single lambda if possible.

Comment: @PresadTelkikar I don't see what is so elegant about it, but if you mean it declares intent better, than yes, but it also has worse performance, [linq-when-to-use-singleordefault-vs-firstordefault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745691/linq-when-to-use-singleordefault-vs-firstordefault-with-filtering-criteria)

Comment: Thanks everyone. I am still learning and sometimes overthink things. I want to get good at LINQ, but I understand now that this is inefficient for this use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to refactor this LINQ into a single lambda expression?

Ignoring the inefficiency of querying a dictionary for a single key value with Linq, no, there is no way to do a non-trivial `Where` and a non-trivial `Select` in a single lambda.

At best you could create a "filtered select" extension method where you pass in two lambdas, but I don't see the value of that over calling two Linq functions.

If you want to get rid of the `ToList` and the indexer, you could use something like `Single` instead of `ToList` to return a single value. Read the docs on `Single`, `SingleOrDefault`, `First`, and `FirstOrDefault` to understand the differences and determine which is appropriate for your needs.

Comment: Thank you for this. Single works to replace ToList. Like I mentioned, I am just trying to practice on my LINQ skills, but I understand now that this is inefficient. Again, I am new to C# and sometimes overthink things.

Comment: No worries-  I was afraid the dictionary example was hiding the real question. I'd still recommend reading the docs on the various methods ti understand the differences and know when to use each one.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary can have only an unique key. So it doesn't make any sense to use linq and tolist() if you looking searching keys. Try this

```
 Console.WriteLine($"Desired output: {myd[1] }");
```

output

```
Desired output: one
```

it makes sense only if you have more complicated search like this

```
var list =  myd.Where(v => v.Key > 2).Select(v =>v.Value).ToList();
```

but it  is one line only. What do you need? A half of line?

or maybe this?

```
Console.WriteLine( myd.Where(v => v.Key ==1).Select(v =>v.Value).FirstOrDefault());
```

but it is the same as the first one, only not so efficient

Comment: I am asking about refactor a LINQ query. I know I can just call the dictionary directly by index. I am using LINQ to search for a key and return the value. I need that value to be a string.