# Point variable to specific element of observable collection

Tags: c#

I'd like to set a variable of type "ReturnOrderDetailLine" to be a specific "ReturnOrderDetailLine" within an "Observable Collection" of "ReturnOrderDetailLine"s.

Identifying the element I am interested in is done via searching for a barcode

```
        public ObservableCollection<ReturnOrderDetailLine> ReturnLines
        {
            get => returnLines;
            set
            {
                returnLines = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ReturnLines));
            }
        }

        public ReturnOrderDetailLine SelectedLine { get; set; }

        protected override void UpdateBarcodePickedOrReturnedQty(string barcodeText)
        {
            var returnDetailLine = (ReturnOrderDetailLine)ReturnLines.Where(s => s.Barcode.Equals(barcodeText));
            SelectedLine = returnDetailLine;
            OnPlusCommand();
        }
```

I have tried using search methods like .select() or .where() but it seems the output of these functions are the same.

I've tried casting the result of .where() to the type I want but I receive a "Specified cast is not valid" error.

I've trawled googled for about an hour now and have gotten no insights.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` is the method you're looking for. Example: `ReturnLines.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Barcode.Equals(barcodeText));`. Other alternatives might be `First()`, `Single()`, and `SingleOrDefault()` based on your needs.

Comment: `returnDetailLine` is not a `ReturnOrderDetailLine` instance, and can therefore not be assigned to `SelectedLine`. `returnDetailLine` is an **enumerable** that represents the ReturnOrderDetailLine instances from `ReturnLines` which match the `Where` criteria. That can technically be zero ReturnOrderDetailLine's , one ReturnOrderDetailLine, two ReturnOrderDetailLine's, or as many ReturnOrderDetailLine's as there are in `ReturnLines` (hence why the `Where` clause returns an **enumerable**)

Comment: @MichalDiviš - Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace - I now understand what a return of "IEnumerable<TSource>" means! Appreciate you taking the time to explain, thank you.

Comment: @emanresu_123 Happy to help. I created an answer out of my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple methods that might satisfy your needs:

- `FirstOrDefault()`: returns a first item of potentially multiple (or default if none exists).
- `First()`: returns a first item of potentially multiple (or throw an exception if none exists).
- `SingleOrDefault()`: assumes that there is a single item and returns it (or default if none exists). Multiple items are a violation of contract, an exception is thrown.
- `Single()`: assumes that there is a single item and returns it (or throw an exception if none exists). Multiple items are a violation of contract, an exception is thrown.

Here's an example of using the `FirstOrDefault()` method in your scenario:

```cs
ReturnOrderDetailLine item = ReturnLines.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Barcode.Equals(barcodeText));
```

More about the differences between the `FirstOrDefault()`, `First()`, `SingleOrDefault()` and `Single()` can be found in this [helpful stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1745709/4317797).